# FFmpeg - Overlay filter. Possible to set eof_action to "pass" through longest file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay 2 files with the FFmpeg overlay filter side by side.

The files contain different durations.  I've played around with the various eof_actions and other settings from the FFmpeg docs, but I can't figure out a way to get my desired interaction.

I want the files to play back side by side on a black canvas, and when the shortest file ends - that area continues to show "black".

I can achieve a proper result if I set my longer file to be the "main" file for the overlay filter AND I set the eof_action to "pass"... However, I want to repeat this command on multiple file pairs and do not know which file is the "longest".

Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to set the eof_action to "pass" through the longest of the two files?

Here is my current filtergraph:

`-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[t1];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[t2]:[t2]pad=1000:500:0:0[p];[p][t1]overlay=x=500:y=0:eof_action=pass[out]" ......`

... The above command works exactly how I want it IF [0:v] is a longer duration than [1:v].  Is there a way to have the same interaction in all cases by setting the "eof_action" to "pass" through the longest file instead of the "main" file?

Comment: Do these files have audio?

Comment: @occvtech were you able to solve this the way you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[t1];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[t2];[t1][t2]hstack[out]"
```

The command above doesn't terminate with the shortest input, but it will freeze the last frame of the shorter input, so you may want to append a black frame at the end of each of the inputs, and then trim out the last frame from the result.

Comment: I just removed a comment... I spoke too soon - dang.

Your above command appears to work with the hstack filter, but I will be encountering different number of input files that are overlayed at different x/y coordinates - so I think I'm stuck with the overlay filter...

Any thoughts on how to achieve a similar interaction with the overlay filter?

Comment: Your Q says you need to overlay side by side. That's what hstack does. For which it needs files of identical height. So, if you have mismatched files, pad/scale as needed to make them the same height. If you have `n` inputs to stack, add `=n` to `hstack`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I tried to simplify my OP so that I didn't over complicate my request.  hstack won't work for me in this case because i need this to work with up to 9 input labels, and they may not be tiled in an even grid.  I think I am stuck using the overlay filter - but then I don't see a way to get the proper eof_action I am seeking.  Do you have any additional thoughts?  Thanks again for the help.